# How do I change the background color of a legend in plant uml?

Tags: plantuml

I've created a legend in a diagram but one of the colors im using is very close to the color of the legend, is there a way to change the back ground color of the legend?

```
legend
|= |= Type |
|<back:D1D3D4>   </back>| Color one |
|<back:#C1D82F>   </back>| Color Two |
endlegend
```

[image]

Comment: There is, afaik, no way to change it. Also no information about that in the [PlantUML Language Guide](http://de.plantuml.com/PlantUML_Language_Reference_Guide.pdf)

Answer (score 16):

You appear to be able to change the background colour of the legend using `skinparam`, although this doesn't seem to be documented:

```
@startuml

skinparam legendBackgroundColor #ff9999

legend
|= |= Type |
|<back:D1D3D4>   </back>| Color one |
|<back:#C1D82F>   </back>| Color Two |
endlegend
@enduml
```

[image: Coloured legend]